# getting the javascript results in python list

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, phantomjs

I use this site to download required info about lat/ lon of districts of India.

```
http://india.csis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/
```

Can I get all the districts of a give state using python? For e.g. if I choose State: maharashtra I get the list of districts like Akola, Raigarh in the next drop down list. I need that info as a python list.

I can see that a javascript function is called and it is getting the data from /api/ directory.

```
function setDistrictList() {
    var selected = "";
    state = $("#state_list").val();
    districts = {};
    url = "/api/getDistrictList";
```

Is it possible that I can get this list of districts programmatically using python?

update:

I have tried this function. But that returns the results and not the Java Script drop down list that I expect.

```
def __getVillageMarkersFromWeb(self,query, state_code=None, district_code=None):
    stateString = '"state":"' + state_code + '"' if state_code is not None else ""
    districtString = ',"district":"' + district_code + '"' if district_code is not None else ""
    f_param = '{' + stateString + districtString + '}'
    params = urllib.urlencode({"q":query,"f":f_param})
    url = "http://india.csis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/geocode-cgi/census_ajax_json.cgi"
    http = httplib2.Http()
    response, markers_xml = http.request(url, "POST", params)
    dom = minidom.parseString(markers_xml)
    markers = dom.getElementsByTagName("marker")
    return markers
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. Since you tagged this with [PhantomJS], you probably want a PhantomJS solution. You can drive PhantomJS through Selenium from Python. Try something yourself and come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

BeautifulSoup allows you to target elements with particular class/id after you've gotten the markup from a page using Requests/urllib/urllib2.

Then you can loop through your BS object and save each to your list.

If the content on a page is generated with JavaScript, [PhantomJS](http://blog.rimthong.com/ghost-in-the-web-scraping-with-phantom-and-casper/) can emulate the JS before the markup is scraped.